# Send new FormData and Datastring together through jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 type data of Ajax with the function is Post data and Upload an images.

So, how can I combine the 2 data type below :

```
var dataString = 'update='+ updateval +'&uid='+ updateuid +'&updatelocation='+ updatelocation +'&update2='+ updateval2 +'&txtbox_name='+ txtbox_name;

data:  new FormData(this) <-- data type of Upload
data: dataString
```

What's the correct syntax here?